# Cannot retrieve string(s) from preferences (settings)

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have encountered a problem in my Android application.  The problem is that for some reason, I can't retrieve the string of a `ListPreference` from my `preferences.xml` file.  Here's the code I tried:

```
private void showUserSettings() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    try {

        String feet = sharedPrefs.getString("feet", "NULL");
        int intfeet = Integer.parseInt(feet);
        int intinches = Integer.parseInt(sharedPrefs.getString("feet", "NULL").trim());
        int weight = Integer.parseInt(sharedPrefs.getString("weight", "NULL").trim());
        int age = Integer.parseInt(sharedPrefs.getString("age", "NULL").trim());
        double calories;
        double inches = ((intfeet * 12) + intinches);
        if (gender.equals("Female")) {
            //BMR = 655 + ( 4.35 x weight in pounds ) + ( 4.7 x height in inches ) - ( 4.7 x age in years )
            calories = 655 + (4.35 * weight) + (4.7 * inches) - (4.7 * age);
        }
        else {
            //66 + ( 6.23 x weight in pounds ) + ( 12.7 x height in inches ) - ( 6.8 x age in years )
            calories = 66.5 + (6.23 * weight) + (12.7 * inches) - (6.8 * age);
        }
        //ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("exercise");
        //CharSequence currText = listPreference.getEntry();
        String exercise = sharedPrefs.getString("exercise", "NULL").toString();
        if (exercise.equals("Sedentary")) {
            double sedentary = calories * 1.2;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sedentary + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (exercise.equals("Light")){
            double light = calories * 1.375;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), light + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (exercise.equals("Moderate")){
            double moderate = calories * 1.55;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), moderate + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (exercise.equals("Very active")) {
            double veryactive = calories * 1.725;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), veryactive + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (exercise.equals("Extra active")) {
            double extraactive = calories * 1.9;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), extraactive + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uh oh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Whenever it gets to the second if/else statement, it directly goes to the else statement.  I don't know why it is doing this.  I have searched SO and Google, but with no avail.  I basically hit a brick wall.  Any help regarding this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about when it gets here, `if (exercise.equals("Extra active")) {`, it just goes to the `else`? Have you set a breakpoint to see what the value of `exercise` is? Also, you shouldn't need to call `toString()` on a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your exercise conditionals are separate and the else is only tied to the last if statement.  Use `else if` to bind them all together in the way I believe you intend.